# Validação com Toast e inserção no banco

Tags: java, android, mobile

Estou me arriscando no Android, sou muito iniciante e estou com problemas na minha primeira inserção no banco de dados. Preciso além disso, validar os campos do meu formulário antes de fazer o envio. Caso seja possível, um toque de boas práticas vai bem também.

Aquisição dos dados do formulário e chamada do método para salvar os dados no banco:

```
public void GetActionValues(View objView) {
        EditText etProjectName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtProjectName);
        EditText etCustomerName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCustomerName);
        EditText etCustomerEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCustomerEmail);
        EditText etCustomerPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCustomerPhone);

        Project project = new Project();


        /* VALIDAÇÃO DE CAMPOS */
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(etProjectName.getText().toString()))
            project.Name = etProjectName.getText().toString();      
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.msg_validation_ProjectName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            etProjectName.findFocus();
        }
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(etCustomerName.getText().toString())) 
            project.CustomerName = etCustomerName.getText().toString();     
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.msg_validation_CustomerName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            etCustomerName.findFocus();
        }
        project.CustomerEmail = etCustomerEmail.getText().toString();
        project.CustomerPhone = etCustomerPhone.getText().toString();

        SaveProject(project);
    }

    public void SaveProject(Project projectObject) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("Name", projectObject.Name);
        values.put("CustomerName", projectObject.CustomerName);
        values.put("CustomerEmail", projectObject.CustomerEmail);
        values.put("CustomerPhone", projectObject.CustomerPhone);
        _context.insert("Project", null, values);

        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.msg_project_save_success,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Nesta parte, debugando o código noto que ele entra no else na validação e não exibe as mensagens do Toast, passando pelo else porém sem mostrar nada e nem dar o foco no campo.

```
Model DBHelper:
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final static String CREATE_SQL_Profile_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE Profile (_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                                                            "CostHour FLOAT NOT NULL)" ;

    private final static String CREATE_SQL_Project_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE Project (_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                                                            "Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " +
                                                            "CustomerName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL," +
                                                            "CustomerEmail VARCHAR(50)," +
                                                            "CustomerPhone VARCHAR(50)," +
                                                            "WorkingTime VARCHAR(50)," +
                                                            "AmountMoney FLOAT)" ;

    private final static String DELETE_SQL_Profile_TABLE = "DROP TRABLE Profile";

    private final static String DELETE_SQL_Project_TABLE = "DROP TRABLE Project";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(db != null){     
            db.execSQL(CREATE_SQL_Profile_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_SQL_Project_TABLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL(DELETE_SQL_Profile_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DELETE_SQL_Project_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_SQL_Profile_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_SQL_Project_TABLE);
    }

    public DBHelper(Context context, String name, int version){
        super(context, name, null, version);
    }
}
```

Debug:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nota-se que não estão chegando todos os parametros do formulário, esta faltando o "CustomerName", que no SQL não pode ser nulo. Mas o procedimento parece estar correto.

Comment: Em vez de `.findFocus();` deve ser `.requestFocus();`

Comment: quando vc chama `R.string.msg_validation_ProjectName`, ele vai te retornar um inteiro que referencia essa string no seu resources. Use ao invéz disso `getString(R.string.msg_validation_ProjectName)` e use também .requestFocus();` como o @ramaral disse.

Comment: algum ponha a resposta :) funcionou sim! Valeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algumas dicas:

No método `GetActionValues(View objView)` estão sendo feitas duas verificações em sequência, caso os dois campos (Name e CustomerName) estejam inválidos, um Toast será enviado em cima do outro, e portanto somente o segundo Toast ficará visível.

---

Poderia ser feita também uma validação de que se um campo obrigatório (Name ou CustomerName por exemplo) estiver inválido, não chamar o método `SaveProject()`. Da maneira como está implementado se o `CustomerName` for nulo, será mostrado um Toast, o EditText vai requisitar o foco, mas mesmo assim o `insert` no banco será chamado.

---

Última dica, seguindo uma convenção de nomenclatura, nomes de métodos devem iniciar com letra minúscula. Se quiser ler mais sobre isso: http://www.devmedia.com.br/convencoes-de-codigo-java/23871